# How can a real device be registered to and recognized by the production MobileFirst 7.0 Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

We have successfully configured a MobileFirst 7.0 server for testing and production environment, and deploy an application on it. But after several real devices installing the App (both iOS and Android), we CAN NOT see any devices in the worklightconsole.

```
No device registered in this runtime.
```

[image]

So how can these devices which havd already installed the app be recognized and displayed in the worklightconsole device tab.

Comment: Does your application actually connect to the MFP Server?  The most common case I see where this happens is when an app never connects to the server, so the server is never actually aware of the device (and it never shows up in the "Devices" tab).

Comment: @patbarron yes, that's the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html

> **userIdentityRealms**
>   A comma-separated ordered list of user identity realms for OAuth
>   authentication. The realms should be ordered by preference. The first
>   successfully authenticated realm in this list is selected as the user
>   identity realm. If the list is empty, or no realm in the list was
>   authenticated, the ID token contains no identity information. This
>   element is optional and the default value is an empty list.
>
> `<userIdentityRealms>WASLTPARealm,
>   CustomAuthenticatorRealm</userIdentityRealms>`
>
> Note: This attribute is
>   used to set user identity in the OAuth-based flows. For the classic
>   (pre-V7.0) flows, see the documentation for the [customSecurityTest
>   security test](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_security_tests.html?lang=en-us).

You'll need to provide your realm name in the application-descriptor.xml file in order for the app to be listed in the Devices tab.

Comment: Hi Adar, after connect to MF server, device are displayed in the tab, but with blank USER ID and FRIEND NAME (check here : http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/5fd37818jw1eu2dz80kngj21go0octds.jpg) ,I've done things after user login like `var userIdentity = {
    userId: userinfo.userId,
    loginName:userinfo.loginName,
    displayName: username, 
    userRoleId:userinfo.roleId,
    attributes: {
     foo: "bar"
    }
  };` and `WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);` but still got blank.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by losing connecting with the MF server.

Simple checking the connection by use the following code:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
        onFailure: onConnectFailure
    });

}

function onConnectSuccess() {
    WL.Logger.debug ("Connecting to MobileFirst Server.");
}

function onConnectFailure(data){
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("CAN NOT Connecting to MobileFirst Server", "try it again", 
        [{
            text : 'Reload',
            handler : WL.Client.reloadApp 
        },
        {
            text: 'Close',
            handler : function() {}
        }]);
}
```